# Django CMS - Unable to modify structure of a newly added webpage

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm completely new to Django CMS and I'm stuck with this issue.

I have added a new module to an existing Django project and created a new Html page. This is the templates configuration in **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'site_cms', 'templates'),
                 ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
                'core.context_processors.request_info',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In the new page, I'm extending the home page of the website as I've seen other pages do. This is the home page **home.html** (/core/templates/core/home.html):

```
{% load i18n easy_thumbnails_tags static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load staticfiles i18n menu_tags%}
</head>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
```

This is my new page **newpage.html** (/newpage/templates/newpage/newpage.html)

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% load easy_thumbnails_tags i18n static core_filters bootstrap4 %}
{% block content %}
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <div class="container">
```

After creating the new page, I added it to the website main-menu through the Django CMS bar. I selected the template for the page to the one the parent (home) uses. I see this makes changes only in Database. OK, so now I have this page in the main-page menu, and in the Django CMS module.

The problem I have is that I cannot edit the structure of the page from the Django CMS bar. When I click on "Edit" button, I see the structure icon (www.localhost:8000/newpage/?structure), but the button is not active. I want to be able to add widgets to this page. How can I do that?How can I active the osibility to modify the structure?

On this project, I see some pages have this posibility to modify the structure of the page, and others don't. Maybe relevant, when I check the source of other pages with this posibility, I see:

```
    'request': {
        'language': 'en',
        'model': 'cms.page',
        'page_id': '3',
        'pk': '3',
        'url': '/admin/cms/page/resolve/',
        'toolbar': '/admin/cms/usersettings/cms-toolbar/'
    },
```

on my newpage I see:

```
    'request': {
        'language': 'en',
        'model': '',
        'page_id': '103',
        'pk': '',
        'url': '/admin/cms/page/resolve/',
        'toolbar': '/admin/cms/usersettings/cms-toolbar/'
    },
```

I use Python 3.6.9, Django 1.11.17 and django-cms 3.5.3.
I know I can be missing some relevant info/code to show. Please ask, I'll post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the editable parts of CMS. Primarily this would be a placeholder so that you can add content via the structure view.

Change `newpage.html` to something like;

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% load cms_tags easy_thumbnails_tags i18n static core_filters bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <div class="container">
        {% placeholder "content" %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now you'll see a placeholder called "content" in the structure view which you can add plugins to.

Comment: Thanks @markwalker_ , that fixed the button. Unfortunately, the structure tab is completely grey and no elements inside, nor any option to add any plugin like I see other pages have. Do you know what I'm still missing ?

Comment: You mean the structure button is disabled? That happens if there aren't any placeholders on the page. If the structure tab opens, it will show the placeholders on the page and have the '+' button which then allows you to add plugins. See here; https://ibb.co/JsYvc3y

Comment: Hello @markwalker_. Well, `{% placeholder "content" %}` enabled the button, but I see no option to add elements. In other pages I have Content block (where you have Text) and option to add elements to it. See https://ibb.co/MfPKrBk . How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @start.stack1 ok that isn't obvious what's causing that. Do you specify a setting of `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`? If you change the placeholder name does it show up?

Comment: I have empty configuration in `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {}` . No, if I change `{% placeholder "content" %}` to something else like `{% placeholder "contrrenttt" %}` then the structure button is disabled again.